# Why is `dask.distributed` not parallelizing the first run of my workflow?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess, dask, dask-distributed

Bear with me, this is a very specific setup; consider the following code:

```
# sys.version = 3.6.6
# distributed.__version__ = 1.22.0

import subprocess
from distributed import Client
from time import sleep

def start():
    subprocess.check_output(['bash', '-c', 'ls'])

class Container:
    def __init__(self, fn):
        self.fn = fn
    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.fn(*args, **kwargs)

%%time
with Client(processes=True) as client:
    f = client.submit(Container(start).run, pure=False)
    a = client.submit(Container(lambda x: sleep(5)).run, f, pure=False)
    b = client.submit(Container(lambda x: sleep(5)).run, f, pure=False)
    res = client.gather([a, b])
# Wall time: 10.7 s
```

I've done some other more intricate tests and for some reason `distributed` does not compute `a` and `b` in parallel.  However, this is *very* specific to the current setup:

- it works as expected if `processes=False`
- it works as expected if the functions are submitted directly
- it works as expected if I keep the `Client` alive and submit this same graph a *second time* (so there is some sort of warming up that needs to happen)

This must be *something* to do with how `Container` is pickled and the fact that I'm spinning up a new `subprocess`, but I'd love to understand why this happens and how to preemptively recognize this situation in the future.

Comment: Yup.  That's a weird one.  I don't have an easy answer for you.

Comment: Does your real code also use lambdas?

Comment: No, it does not

Comment: check with `pickle.dumps(Container(...))` if it can be pickled at all